# Debugging ROS package with Qtcreator?

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all

I want to integrate ROS with Qtcreator. When I use Qtcreator to debugging the existing ROS package, I met this problem:
**Lowest section in /usr/lib/libicudata.so.42 is .note.gnu.build-id at 000000f4**
Anyone knows how to solve this problem? And is there anyone that using ROS with Qtcreator successfully?

Thanks
Tony

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34966/debugging-ros-package-with-qtcreator???/) by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

QtCreator is a good choice for ROS related development as it natively "understands" CMake projects. For easy debugging, the relevant node can be compiled as "Debug" or "RelWithDebInfo" and then started normally via a launch file. One can then attach the QtCreator debugger to the running node via "Debug"->"Start Debugging"->"Attach to running external Application...". This works very well for me and has the advantage that one does not have to setup parameters/remappings etc. for the node in a separate step.

/edit: It is required to follow the instructions in [the answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process) if one gets a "ptrace operation not allowed" error.

Edit:  To make debug build add `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` to  CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2012-09-20**:
Hi Stefan, I tried to do just as you say, but I'm having problems with ptrace not being allowed. Also, doesn't this mean you cannot set breakpoints from QtCreator? If I try to debug the relevant node from QtCreator itself it seems to get stuck in "Setting breakpoints...", though...

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2012-09-21**:
I've been digging a bit deeper and it seems that I can start the debugging from the QtCreator interface, set breakpoints and so on, and everything goes fine until I reach a ros::spin() call. Any idea why this might be?

**Comment by [f_r__](https://answers.ros.org/users/2745/f_r__/) on 2013-06-10**:
How would this work with Groovy/Catkin now that RelWithDebInfo does not seem to make any difference? Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-11**:
Hi, i am not able to debug breakpoints, after attaching, its showing assembly code. I did debug build with set( DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) in cmakelists.txt.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-09-15**:
If you set from CMakeLists.txt, you have to omit the D in front of CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE. Only when setting the definition from command line (e.g. "catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug") you have to add it.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-15**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher thanks it worked

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2015-05-15**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher thanks it worked! As a side note, I had to run qtcreator with "sudo" for the debugging from Qtcreator to work; otherwise it works perfectly.

**Comment by [anonymous23097](https://answers.ros.org/users/23097/anonymous23097/) on 2015-07-08**:
@jespestana Instead of running qtcreator as sudo, you should allow ptrace of non-child-processes for gdb

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin 
sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip /usr/bin/gdb
```

or enable ptrace globally `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` (not recommended)

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-10-15**:
Any experience with `gdbserver` on this one? I'm asking this because the node has to run on a remote system where  I cannot use Qt Creator. The node also depends on the hardware there so I can't run in locally. The only solution omho is using `gdbserver`. However it doesn't seem to work properly.

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2015-10-15**:
You can ros-launch a node and make it start with gdbserver. The node is not started until you connect to it using Qt. To do so, try adding the launch-prefix "xterm -e gdbserver localhost:10000", and connect to it with Qt (both things from the local machine). More info here: http://bit.ly/1OEaVce